# Verilog: $display with _ separator

Tags: verilog

In Verilog, one can conveniently use `_` anywhere in binary and hexadecimal literals. For example, `8'b0101_0011` and `32'hAEBB_23AF` are valid literals.

Is it possible to have `$display` do a similar thing? I'm trying to display a 64-bit signal in hex, which is 16 characters long and difficult to parse visually. I would like a `_` every four characters to ease reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no automatic way to have `$display` do that. But you can format it yourself to do that.

For example, this will print a 64-bit value like you wanted, with a `0x` prefixed to the string.

```
$display("0x%04h_%04h_%04h_%04h", d[63:48], d[47:32], d[31:16], d[15:0]);
```

In this case, it's important to print the leading zeros; that is what the `0` in `04` means.

If I were doing this and using it more than once I would also wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

If your simulator supports SystemVerilog syntax, here is a function which can be used to display integers up to 64 bits.  Wider values require multiple calls to the function.  The function can display values as binary, decimal or hex.

```
module tb;

function string fmt (longint num, string radix, int width = 1);
    // Convert integer input into a string with underscores
    // for $display.  For example: 12345 -> 12_345.
    // radix should be [d|h|b].
    // width can be used for zero-padding on the left.
    // Any x/z passed into num gets converted to 0.
    // Reals passed into num are rounded to an integer.
    // Values greater than 64-bit are truncated.
    int pos, chars;
    string str, str2, fmtstr;
    str2 = "";

    fmtstr = {"%0", $sformatf("%0d", width), radix};
    str = $sformatf(fmtstr, num);

    chars = (radix == "d") ? 3 : 4;
    pos = 0;
    for (int i = str.len()-1; i>=0; i--) begin
        pos++;
        str2 = {str.getc(i), str2};
        if (pos % chars == 0) str2 = {"_", str2};
    end

    // Remove any leading underscore
    if (str2.getc(0) == "_") begin
        str2 = str2.substr(1, str2.len()-1);
    end
    return str2;
endfunction


reg [127:0] big;
reg [ 63:0] data;

initial begin
    data = 64'hfeed1234;
    $display(fmt(data, "h"));

    $display(fmt(98765, "d"));
    $display(fmt(33, "b", 8));

    big = 128'h123456789abcdef0777788889999aaaa;
    $display({fmt(big[127:64], "h"), "_", fmt(big[63:0], "h", 16)});
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
feed_1234
98_765
0010_0001
1234_5678_9abc_def0_7777_8888_9999_aaaa
```